# Please Explain scss variables

Tags: sass

Can anyone explain about **scss** and basics, about how to use **variables**,**operators**,**mixins**,and **partials**?

Comment: why not just read the documentation? http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$color: red; // variable

%button-default { // placeholder (doesn't generate css)
    color: $color;
}

@mixin button() { // mixin
    @extend %button-default; // get placeholder styles

    @content;
}

button {
    @include button() { // call mixin and pass content to it
         font-size: 16px;
    }
}

a {
    @include button(); // just call mixin
}
```

[Demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/dd0f0b2124dd8bb875705a615bacf200)

To compile scss use gulp, grunt, webpack etc.